# Strange characters appearing in tikz plot

Tags: characters

for some strange reason, when I draw a plot with tikz, some strange unicode characters appear in the plot. [image]

The original code is:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmin}{-5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmax}{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ymin}{-2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ymax}{6}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\tick}{0.1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\k}{0.7}
\draw[->] (\xmin,0) -- (\xmax,0) node[anchor=north] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,\ymin) -- (0,\ymax) node[anchor=east] {$V(x)$};
  \draw[very thick]•
    plot[domain=-4:4]•
    (
      {\x},
      {(\k/2)*\x*\x}
    );
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Harmonic potential}
\label{harmpot}
\end{figure}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The strange character is possibly the shown here strange (for LaTeX): "•". Get rid of it and try again. Possibly your newline ("›") is strange too and depends on your editor ... but the previous is more important if your editor is really compatible with LaTeX (and plain text) and you didn't just added that to post the question

Comment: To add code in your question, just paste it ... mark it ... and press the button : `{}`

Comment: When I remove all `>` on beginning of your code lines and `•` your code works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the invisible control characters after

- `\draw[very thick]`
- `plot[domain=-4:4]`

then it works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmin}{-5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmax}{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ymin}{-2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ymax}{6}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\tick}{0.1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\k}{0.7}
\draw[->] (\xmin,0) -- (\xmax,0) node[anchor=north] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,\ymin) -- (0,\ymax) node[anchor=east] {$V(x)$};
  \draw[very thick]
    plot[domain=-4:4]
    (
      {\x},
      {(\k/2)*\x*\x}
    );
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Harmonic potential}
\label{harmpot}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Than you very much!